# ignore a specific endpoint in the service worker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

Basically I am working with an online/offline app. I developped a custom hook to detect wether a user has connection or not. For this I am sending a random fetch request. However the service worker is intercepting the request and send a 200 even though the user is clearly offline. My question is, can I ingore a specific endpoint in the service worker ?

```
const checkOnline = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('/test.test');

            setOnline(response.ok);
            console.log('response.source', response.url)
        } catch {
            setOnline(false);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect internet connection status via [window.navigator.onLine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine). No need to make a fake request

Comment: this is not reliable enough in my case, the question here is how to blacklist an endpoint with the service worker

Comment: Ok, please post the code of your service worker